# Datediff in minute in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I am using following SQL query to find difference between two datetime fields which is calculate night time shift,

For example

today work time is evening 190957 til next date morning 071152 so the between time in fab minute is 628, but  out fab time will  be calculate 798 min(Over calculate, more than IN fab time).  so i want calculate in accurate minute.

```
       SELECT 
             GROUP_SCANTIMECAL.EP_EMP_ID
        ,SUM(CAST(GROUP_SCANTIMECAL.INFAB_MIN AS FLOAT)) AS INFAB
            ,SUM(CAST(GROUP_SCANTIMECAL.OUTFAB_MIN AS FLOAT)) AS OUTFAB
            FROM
            (
          SELECT SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_NAME
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_DEPT
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SECTION
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SHIFT
           ,SCANHIST.EP_TRANS_LOC
            ,DATEDIFF(MI,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME),
            CAST(STUFF(STUFF(NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) AS INFAB_MIN
            ,DATEDIFF(MI,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME),
            CAST(STUFF(STUFF(PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) AS OUTFAB_MIN
            FROM [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SCAN_HIST] SCANHIST

            OUTER APPLY
            (
            SELECT TOP 1
             NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_ID
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_NAME
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_DEPT
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_SECTION
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_ID
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_TRANS_DESC
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_TRANS_LOC
            FROM [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SCAN_HIST] NEXTSCAN

            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_EMP_INFO] EMPINFO
            ON EMPINFO.EP_EMP_ID = NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_ID


            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_CALENDAR] SHIFTCAL
            ON SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_NAME = NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            AND SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_DATE = LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)

           JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_DESC] SHIFTDESC
           ON SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT

           WHERE 1=1
          AND SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_ID = NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_ID
           AND NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE > SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE
          AND NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE < CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'N1')
           THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,+1,LEFT(NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)),112) + ' ' + 
           REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
           ELSE CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R1' OR FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R2') 
           THEN 
           LEFT(NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' + 
           REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
           ELSE 
           LEFT(NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' + 
           REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') END END
          AND NEXTSCAN.EP_TRANS_LOC = 'OUT'
          ORDER BY NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE
            )NEXTSCAN

            OUTER APPLY
          (
            SELECT TOP 1
           PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_ID
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_NAME
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_DEPT
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_SECTION
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_ID
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_TRANS_DESC
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_TRANS_LOC
            FROM [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SCAN_HIST] PREVSCAN

            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_EMP_INFO] EMPINFO
             ON EMPINFO.EP_EMP_ID = PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_ID

            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_CALENDAR] SHIFTCAL
            ON SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_NAME = PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            AND SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_DATE = LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)

            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_DESC] SHIFTDESC
            ON SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT

           WHERE 1=1
           AND SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_ID = PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_ID
            AND PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE > SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE
           AND PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE < CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'N1') 
           THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,+1,LEFT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)),112) + ' ' + 
           REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
           ELSE CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R1' OR FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R2') 
            THEN 
            LEFT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' + 
            REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
            ELSE 
            LEFT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' + 
            REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') END END
           AND PREVSCAN.EP_TRANS_LOC = 'IN'
            ORDER BY PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE
            )PREVSCAN

             JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_EMP_INFO] EMPINFO
             ON EMPINFO.EP_EMP_ID = SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID


            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_CALENDAR] SHIFTCAL
            ON SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SHIFT
           AND SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_DATE = LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)

            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_DESC] SHIFTDESC
           ON SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT

         WHERE 1=1
            AND SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE >= FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE
           AND SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE < CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'N1') 
             THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,+1,LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)),112) + ' ' +
               REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') ELSE
             CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R1' OR FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R2')
              THEN 
              LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' + 
             REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','')
              ELSE 
              LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' +
                REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') END END
            AND SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID = FIRSTSCAN.EP_EMP_ID
            AND SCANHIST.EP_TRANS_LOC = 'IN'
            )GROUP_SCANTIMECAL

           GROUP BY GROUP_SCANTIMECAL.EP_EMP_ID


              )SCANTIMECAL
```

Comment: Things will continue to grow more complex if you continue to store these times in columns with inappropriate types. Why are these not being stored as `datetime` values? (The issue is that the bare times are both being treated as if they're on the same day - and the difference between 07:11:52 and 19:09:57 is 718 minutes)

Comment: Dear Damien, thanks for reply, may i know how to separate calculate in nite time (after 12 pm next day) ?

Comment: `DATEADD(day,1,<datetime value that should be treated as being on the next day>)`?

Comment: Yes. it should be treated as being on the next day